How to appropriately group participants from a 5-point experience scale (e.g., no experience to expert) for analysis?
I am analyzing participant data collected using a 5-point self-reported experience scale:
1 = No experience
2 = Beginner
3 = Intermediate
4 = Advanced
5 = Expert
I want to create broader groups for statistical analysis. Specifically, I’m considering combining categories into Novice (e.g., 1–3) and Experienced (e.g., 4–5) or exploring other combinations, such as grouping Intermediate (3) with Advanced (4) and Expert (5).
My questions are:

What are appropriate methods to justify such groupings?
Would methods like Principal Component Analysis (PCA) or clustering be a
valid approach to form these groups based on underlying patterns in
the data?
Are there best practices for validating whether these groupings preserve meaningful
differences in participant characteristics or outcomes?

Context:
I have additional data about participant performance and usability scores, which could be used to inform grouping decisions.
The sample sizes for some categories (e.g., Intermediate = 4 participants) are small, motivating the need for broader groups.
I would appreciate guidance on statistical or data-driven techniques to create these broader groups while ensuring validity.
